# PTIJ: Why are fields safe places to tell secrets?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In [Berachos 8b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.8b.13?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he), we're taught the following:

> וּכְשֶׁיּוֹעֲצִין — אֵין יוֹעֲצִין אֶלָּא בַּשָּׂדֶה
>
> When you give advice, only give advice in the field.

Why? As Rashi explains:

> אלא בשדה – דאמרי אינשי אזנים לכותל:
>
> "Only in the field" – as people say, the walls have ears.

Why is the Gemara only concerned for walls having ears, yet it's perfectly safe for one to advise in the field where the corn has ears and the potatoes have eyes?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

"Shibboleth" can be translated from Biblical Hebrew to mean : "ear of grain".

In Judges 12:1-6, the word was used by the men of Gilead to identify and catch clandestine Ephraimites trying to cross the river.

**"..And they said to him, "Say now 'Shibboleth,' " and he said "Sibboleth," and he was not prepared to pronounce it properly, and they grabbed him...."**

Ever since this incident, the Jews do not trust or accept any messages transmitted via a "shibboleth" for fear of miscommunication. Therefore speaking in the field within "earshot" of ripening grain doesn't matter, as no one will believe what was repeated anyway.

**Devarim 32:10 "He found them in a desert land, and in a desolate, howling wasteland. He encompassed them and bestowed understanding upon them; He protected them as the ("apple") of His eye."**

We see that when bestowing understanding (giving secret advice) one goes to a desolate place (like an open field) and one is still not worried that the secrets will be told to the world by listening potatoes.

As the verse said: the bestowal of understanding is protected like the apple of the eye.

What is the verse reffering to? What is the apple of the eyes??

This is the potato which is called "Tapuach-Adamah" in Hebrew. ("apple of the  ground") Since it has eyes, scripture refers to the potato by the eyes and still promises that they are guarded and hence cannot reveal secrets.

Answer (score 1):

Since corn and potatoes are killed when they are harvested, they would be unable to reveal any of the secrets that the corn might *hear*. Also since the potatoes only have eyes, they would be unable to actually know what secrets might have been told.

Comment: Maybe the potatoes can read lips?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the statement here. Rashi is actually preempting your very question. You just have to read it with the next two words as well:

> דאמרי אינשי אזנים לכותל בדבר אחר
>
> That which people say "the walls have ears" is another matter.

Rashi is clearly saying that the reason for confining advice to the field is *not* that the walls have ears. The walls having ears is a different matter entirely that has nothing to do with where you give advice. How does Rashi know this? Simple – it's an explicit verse (Psalms 135):

> מעשה ידי אדם פה להם ולא ידברו עינים להם ולא יראו אזנים להם ולא יאזינו
>
> The creations of man – they have mouths but cannot talk, they have eyes but cannot see, they have ears but cannot hear.

It is thus clear that walls (which are creations of man) have ears but they cannot hear. So obviously the concern is not that the walls will hear the secrets. The concern is something else entirely.

The reason why advice should be confined to the field is that, as mentioned a few pages earlier (Berachot 3b), women are not in the fields:

> דהא אשה בדברא לא שכיחא
>
> For a woman in the field is uncommon.

Thus, it is good to confine advice to the fields because there will be no women there to overhear it.

But do we find that there is normally a concern of women revealing secrets? Indeed we do! The Talmud (Shabbat 33b) states:

> כי תקיף גזירתא א"ל לבריה נשים דעתן קלה עליהן דילמא מצערי לה ומגליא לן
>
> When the decree became stronger he said to his son "women, their minds are flighty on them; perhaps they will torture her and she will reveal us".

Thus, the Talmud back in Berachot is saying to confine advice to the fields because then no women will overhear it so you won't have to worry that the women will reveal any secrets. Rashi only mentions the fact that walls have ears to tell us that that is *not* the reason for the Talmud's directive.

Comment: You can also support that from Berachot 48b, נשים דברניות הן

Answer (score -1):

You're right. Corn has ears. And the majority of corn becomes syrup. So, any secrets that it may have had become sweet nothings that are whispered into their own ears. Nothing to worry about, thank God!

Similarly, it's a good thing that potatoes have eyes. The eyes sprout and cloud the potato's vision. Thus, any secrets that might have been in the eyes would be cloudy and blurry almost immediately, and no one would be able to understand them.